# Vagrant and php7 installation fails

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, php-7

Today I wanted to install php7 from scratch. I saw some tutorials and now my vagrantfile looks like:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 2048
      v.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

The bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi

apt-get update

apt-get install -y make

apt-get install -y php-pear 
apt-get install -y git-core 
apt-get install -y autoconf 
apt-get install -y bison 
apt-get install -y libxml2-dev 
apt-get install -y libbz2-dev 
apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev 
apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev 
apt-get install -y libltdl-dev 
apt-get install -y libpng-dev 
apt-get install -y libpspell-dev 
apt-get install -y libreadline-dev
apt-get install -y libssl-dev
apt-get install -y install libt1-dev

mkdir -p /etc/php7/conf.d
mkdir -p /etc/php7/cli/conf.d
mkdir /usr/local/php7

cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git --depth=1
cd php-src
./buildconf
./configure \
        --prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
        --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 \
        --enable-calendar \
        --enable-exif \
        --enable-dba \
        --enable-ftp \
        --with-gettext \
        --with-gd \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --with-mcrypt \
        --with-mhash \
        --enable-mysqlnd \
        --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
        --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
        --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
        --with-openssl \
        --enable-pcntl \
        --with-pspell \
        --enable-shmop \
        --enable-soap \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-sysvmsg \
        --enable-sysvsem \
        --enable-sysvshm \
        --enable-wddx \
        --with-zlib \
        --enable-zip \
        --with-readline \
        --with-curl \
        --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
        --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli/conf.d
make
make test
make install
```

I use vagrant version 1.7.4 and virtual box version 5.0.10.

I get an error in the compilation process. What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I tested all commands in the vagrant ssh, step by step. Until `make` everything works ok, but `make test` causes this output:
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error that you're receiving?

Comment: Add screenshot and some more details about the error.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile the master branch of PHP7, which is a development branch and not stable. You should try to compile a stable release instead.

Just after cloning the git repository, you must checkout the stable release.

```
 git checkout tags/php-7.0.0
```

However, I recommend that you install PHP7 from a PPA ([Personal Package Archive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)) instead of compiling it.

Ondřej Surý maintains`ppa:ondrej/php-7.0`, which can be installed as follows:

```
$ apt-get install python-software-properties
$ add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
```

PHP7 can then be installed with:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get purge php5-fpm && apt-get --purge autoremove && apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql
```

For further instructions, Bjørn Johansen has written [How to upgrade to PHP 7 on Ubuntu](https://bjornjohansen.no/upgrade-to-php7)

Comment: What is a PPA? Can you write it out?

Comment: PPAs (Personal Package Archives) allow you to update your Ubuntu to the latest version of a package, even if your Ubuntu version is lagging behind. I've edited the answer with a link to a SO question.

Comment: ppa:ondrej/php-7.0 appears to have been merged intoppa:ondrej/php

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

which should install the compiler and a bunch of related/needed packages